# Mock a method call inside the afterPropertiesSet() method of InitializingBean

Tags: spring, junit, spring-webflux

**Scenario :**
I have a class that extends `InitializingBean`. In the afterPropertiesSet() method I am calling another class method, `accessTokenWebClient.getAccessToken("")`.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ApplicationTokenWarmup implements InitializingBean {


  @Autowired
  private AccessTokenWebClient accessTokenWebClient;

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {

          AccessToken accessToken = accessTokenWebClient.getAccessToken("applicationName").block();
          doSomethingWithAccessToken(accessToken);
  }
 }
```

I am trying to write the below Junit test case for the above class. By default, spring automatically calls `afterPropertiesSet()` of the classes extending `InitializingBean` during the context initializing phase.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    ApplicationTokenWarmup.class
    AccessTokenWebClient.class
})
@WebFluxTest
class ApplicationTokenWarmupTests {

  @MockBean
  private AccessTokenWebClient accessTokenWebClient; 

  @Test
  void shouldGetToken() {

    Mockito.doReturn(Mono.just(AccessTokenFixture.M2M_TOKEN_REMOTE)).when(accessTokenWebClient.getAccessToken("applicationName")); //NOT CALLED

  }
}
```

**Problem:**
Since the `ApplicationTokenWarmup.afterPropertiesSet()` method is called before the `shouldGetToken()` test-case, I am unable to mock the `accessTokenWebClient.getAccessToken("applicationName")` call. Due to this, it throws the below error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block()" because the return value of "com....token.cache.service.AccessTokenWebClient.getAccessToken(String)" is null
```

**Question :**
How can I mock the call `accessTokenWebClient.getAccessToken("applicationName")` so that I can return a dummy token value and call `doSomethingWithAccessToken(accessToken)`?